# Converting List<String> to String using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have values in an `ArrayList` as `Value1, Value2, Value3`.
Now i need to return them in a way as a Single `String` as `Value1_Value2_Value3` using Java `Streams`.

I've tried this but it didn't work

```
myList.stream().map((s)->s+"_").toString();
```

I've also tried `collect(toList());` but I'm not sure how to proceed further to convert it to a `String`.

How can I do it?

Comment: use `collect(Collectors.joining("_"))`

Comment: Why not just use `String.join("_", myList)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `myList` already contains `String` (or any other `CharSequence`), then you don't need streams at all, simply call [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)):

```
String joined = String.join("_", myList);
```

Otherwise you can use [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) to produce `String` from any old stream:

```
String joined = myList.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("_"));
```

Comment: From title of the question it seems me OP is using a `List<String>`, so `map` could be omitted.

Comment: @dariosicily: the whole second line is unnecessary if it's really a `List<String>`, which is why I put the simpler version first.

Comment: Agree with you about everything, my consideration was based about the fact OP was trying to solve the problem using streams probably not being aware of `String.join`.

Comment: @dariosicily: which is literally what I've written in the first paragraph of my answer. If they don't read the text, but just copy the code, then no amount of clarification will help them.